# ssh tunnel and rdesktop in one line

Tags: ssh, shell-scripting, tunnel, rdesktop

To access a windows machine remotely I have to tunnel through a ubuntu server of mine. To setup the tunnel I have

```
ssh -l root -C -L 9999:windowsmachine:23389 myserver
```

Then I have to open another console and run

```
rdesktop -u user -password -f localhost:9999
```

How can I combine these in a single command or script?

Answer (score 1):

(**Disclaimer**: See comments for a more efficient solution.)

This is tricky for a number of reasons:

- `ssh` needs to run in the foreground to hold the connection open. This makes it challenging to do this within a single instance of a shell, because the second command needs to execute in parallel to it being foreground.
- You can't test for the return status of the `ssh` command, because the connection will have closed by then. This means the resktop command will fire regardless of whether ssh authentication succeeded.
- For the `rdesktop` command to not be interactive, it needs to supply the password in the command line. Storing the password in the script is a bad idea.

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Request password, no echo
read -s RDP_PW

# Insert password validation here (i.e. make sure we got input)

# Execute sleep+rdesktop in a background subshell, redirect STDOUT to /dev/null.
( sleep 5; rdesktop -u user -p$RDP_PW -f localhost:9999 ) >/dev/null &

# Run the ssh command. We have 5 seconds establish the tunnel.
ssh -l root -C -L 9999:windowsmachine:23389 myserver
```

Adjust the sleep statement as needed. You may want to remove the /dev/null redirection until you're sure this works. You also may want to redirect STDERR.

A better approach relies on the terminal program you're using within X, or whether or not you're familiar with a terminal multiplexer. If your terminal program provides a way for you to invoke a command in a new tab, prefix `ssh` with the appropriate command for doing that. If you go the multiplexer route, use the syntax for invoking `ssh` in a new multiplexer window. Dealing with passwords prompts from `ssh` in both cases is up to you.

Comment: You can also use the "-f" and "-N" flags (background, and no remote command execution), then you can run ssh first and rdesktop afterwards without a need for the sleep command.

Comment: @Derek I like your answer much better than my own. :) You should probably submit it as an answer and get the credit, it's the more efficient solution.